# In ALTER ing table ADD() works while modify not in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, addition

```
table - tbl_customer 
tool- phpmyadmin
```

Queries ---

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_customer    <-- All Good
ADD( price int(10) NOT NULL);
```

While ----

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_customer   <-- Not Working
MoDIFY( price float(12,2) NOT NULL);
```

however this works correctly without braces -

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_customer   <-- All Good
MoDIFY price float(12,2) NOT NULL;
```

After little R&D at dev.mysql.com/doc and various other sites i found none is using the braces `()` in `add/modify` query in mysql queries, however my add query is running fine with the braces. I just curious about those braces and the `concept` im missing. Not very good with mysql ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is you can add more than 1 column using add, so the privilege of braces with/without works in add, but you can just modify a single so the privilege of braces is not provided